# Laravel error : Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to select and store multiple data from my form the input name is "property_type", but i get that error 'Array to string conversion ' :
this is my migration :

```
 public function up() {
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('ref')->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('community');
        $table->text('property_type')->nullable();
        $table->integer('floor_number')->nullable();
        
    });
}
```

my model :

```
class Project extends Model implements HasMedia {
 protected $fillable = [
    'ref',
    'name',
    'community',
   'property_type',
    'floor_number',
   
];

  public function setPtypeAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['property_type'] = json_encode($value);
}

/**
 * Get the categories
 *
 */
public function getPtypeAttribute($value) {
    return $this->attributes['property_type'] = json_decode($value);
}
```

the view :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" novalidate action="{{ route("admin.projects.store") }}" >
        @csrf
     
     
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required">property_type</label>
            <select class="form-control  select2 name="property_type[]" id="property_type" required multiple="">
                <option value="php">PHP</option>
                <option value="react">React</option>
                <option value="jquery">JQuery</option>
                <option value="javascript">Javascript</option>
                <option value="angular">Angular</option>
                <option value="vue">Vue</option>
            </select>
           
        </div>
```

my storeprojectrequest :

```
'property_type' => [
            'array',
            'nullable',
        ],
```

i need help !

Comment: is the accessor really called `getPtypeAttribute`? Shouldn't it be called `getPropertyTypeAttribute`? (Case is important as well)

Comment: i change it , now it was stored in the database but , in the index i get json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\OPEN-CRM-1\resources\views\admin\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: if your getter and mutator are working then you only need to use `json_encode` and `json_decode` within those and don't need them elsewhere in your code

Comment: yes i didnt used anywhere i just used in the getter and setter !

Answer (score 1):

Use `casts` in laravel. [casts in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

Add this to the `Project` model:

```
protected $casts = [
        'property_type' => 'array',
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your Accessors and Mutators like this in Your model. these functions are case sensitive

```
public function getPropertyTypeAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}

public function setPropertyTypeAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['property_type'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

if you're using Laravel 8.77 or later also you can use them like below.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

protected function propertyType(): Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(
        fn($value) => json_decode($value),
        fn($value) => json_encode($value)
    );
}
```

the first parameter is the getter and the second one is the setter.